# What technique should I use for loading large xml and display data in JS

Tags: javascript, xml, svg, charts

I am working on an application which is loading XML files and displaying data in SVG charts (line chart). This application needs to be fast.

The problem is that the implementation of this app has already started and it is completely based on JavaScript. I was told that this app needs to load and parse multiple very big XML files (up to 80 MB) and it needs to be very stable. So as JS is not able to parse such big XML files, they are loaded line by line and parsed as strings. When data is parsed, it is displayed in SVG charts which is another problem. There can be a lot of charts with a lot of data so sometimes browser cannot handle it.

My idea was to do it on the server-side, using SAX parsers and lazy loading on charts, but I cannot because people who are going to use it, they want to use it offline.

So now I would like to know if such thing can be done with JS only or do I have to use server or desktop app .

Comment: First hit when I googled "xml parse big javascript" led me to [this library](https://github.com/jahewson/node-big-xml) which claims it parses 1GB and bigger files. So-o-o, have you looked into any libraries to do that for you?

Comment: It is node.js whitch is server-side

Comment: Yes, I know. I didn't feel like doing research on client-side libraries - after all, this is not my problem, I just saw that it seems possible in JS, hence my question.

Comment: Cut the data down first, how could you possibly render 40MB to the display in a way that makes any sense?

Comment: If u have large R&D company wich is collecting data from routers (LTE networs) and you are collecting data 24 hours .. then you want too see router statuses (like CPU/RAM utilization ..)  while tests are running on them ... then it is good to see it :) ... and there are some filters fot those data. So there is no need to display them all ... but sometimes u want to see more than browser can handle

Comment: Provide what the browser can handle/display and when the user interacts with the UA display something else by fetching that subset of the data at that time.

Comment: @RobertLongson I think that this need some better approach, the whole question is more about principes than about libraries ( although a good client side library would be good  ). We have only one problem and that is the browser is unable to handle such a large data, it just can not hold it all in memory. Using a SAX like parser on client side is something that is ( maybe ) achievable but also you will have say a 5 milion lines, how fast you can move around? I don't know javascript but I know one thing, you need to somehow index the file, the question is how.

Comment: Also displaying 40MB of data in one chart is not posible, you will definitely have a huge information loss, so we need to somehow classify or cluster those data. Again how would someone skilled in javascript do that, keeping in mind memory usage and CPU usage ( good response time ). Or if some javascript guru says that this is not possible that OP need to use different technology.

Comment: @Jan As I already explained above break up the data into overview and details. Display the overview and then display the details only when the user zooms in or interacts with the information somehow. Someone skilled in program design would refuse to write anything in javascript that had to interact with a single 40MB lump of data. The OP needs to use a different architecture/design, not a different technology.

Comment: @Robert Longson that is what I was looking for :) ... not do it in JS

Comment: @RobertLongson you can not break up the data using javascipt only on client without the help of almighty server. How can you break then when you can not load them ( or parse them ) in reasonable time. Anyway I agree with you I would do it your way, different design but also different technology.

Comment: @Jan Indeed, a server is going to be a necessary component here.